# SQL Server: READ COMMITTED and UPDLOCK hint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, locking, isolation-level

I am writing a stored procedure that will use by application that function is booking. And it can happen concurrent booking. To handle that, which approach will be suitable?

I am trying to use isolation level "READ COMMITTED" & "UPDLOCK" hint to handle that. Can it be workable? Any comment and solution will be appreciate.

Another question is: if I use that isolation level and hint, can it be shared lock? If so, how can I handle it?

Best Regards,
Reds

Comment: What do you do when a booking occurs? When you're reading from SQL Server, your `SELECT` statement acquires a `shared lock` - but both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` will have to get an **exclusive** lock to insert / change data ...

Comment: When I do booking, I would like to check available quantity of package. If it's enough, I want to proceed. If Transaction for user1 is still running, another concurrent user2 will book. Assume that available quantity is 8, both user are trying to both 5 each. At that time, I would like to return appropriate msg for user2 from stored procedure and I am worrying about dead lock and shared lock will happen to my stored procedure. I want to handle it. Thanks for your comment Marc.

Comment: In addition to what you're doing, make sure you update your booking status from Pending into InProgress and use an update with output clause for the update.